# Как удалить все вхождения элемента из списка(Python)

Tags: python, список

Вопрос как удалить, все вхождения значения из списка равной 'i' (5-ая строка) ремув только первое вхождение удаляет

```
a = input().split()
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) > 1:
        print(i, end=' ')
        a.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нагляднее всего через *списковое включение* делать:

```
a = input().split()
a = [i for i in a if a.count(i) == 1]
print(a)
```

По сути это, конечно, фильтрация, но для настоящей фильтрации именно в список приходится писать лишние конструкции `list` и `lambda`, а *списковое включение* получается максимально коротким и понятным.

Ваш же вариант неправильно работает, потому что вы удаляете элементы из списка, по которому у вас идёт итерация и это ломает процесс итерации. И об этом много раз уже писали тут (чуть не каждый день такие же вопросы).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте filter:

```
a = input().split()
print(a)
print(list(filter(lambda x: a.count(x) == 1, a)))
```

Пример

```
1 2 3 5 4 1 2 0
['1', '2', '3', '5', '4', '1', '2', '0']
['3', '5', '4', '0']
```

Если порядок сохранять необязательно, можно использовать `set`

```
print(list(set(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему коду, надо удалить дубликаты из списка:

```
a = input().split()
a = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю ещё один вариант.   Так как на входе у Вас все равно строка, можно удалить все вхождения из строки, заменив их на пустую строку, а затем преобразовать её  в список. Вот так :

```
    a = input().replace('i', '')
    а = a.split()
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 0, 2, 0, 0]
number = 0
while number in a:
     a.remove(number)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).